# How do I find position of sprite in group?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game in pygame and am trying to figure out a way to make the enemies explode.

Enemies have their class:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(enemy, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(enemy)
        enemy.image = ENEMYIMAGE.convert()
        enemy.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(enemy.image)
        enemy.rect = enemy.image.get_rect()
        enemy.rect.x = x
        enemy.rect.y = y
```

Which is called in main() repeatedly, then added to a group:

```
enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
if spawn_ctr % 700 == 0:
        enemy = Enemy(WINDOWWIDTH, (random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - ENEMYHEIGHT)))
        enemy_group.add(enemy)
    spawn_ctr += 1
```

Lasers are made similarly, that is, there is a Laser class which is called in main(). When the class is called the Laser is added to a group.

My attempt at making the enemies explode:

```
if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(weapon_group, enemy_group, False, True):
    EXPLOSIONSOUND.play()
    EXPLOSIONANIM.play()
    EXPLOSIONANIM.blit(screen, (weapon.rect.x, weapon.rect.y))
```

This does remove the enemy from the group, making it so that

```
enemy_group.draw(screen)
```

does not draw the enemy which was shot and killed.

But, the explosion actually occurs at the player. How might someone rewrite this in a better way?

Comment: You need to find out which sprite collides, not just whether any in the group do, and set the `x, y` from *that sprite*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the return value of `pygame.sprite.groupcollide` to sort through the results. Instead of what you have now, try this:

```
for enemy,colls in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemy_group, weapon_group, True, False):
    if colls:
        EXPLOSIONSOUND.play()
        EXPLOSIONANIM.play()
        EXPLOSIONANIM.blit(screen, enemy.rect.center)
```

`pygame.sprite.groupcollide` returns a dict whose keys are every sprite in group 1 and whose values are the sprites in group 2 they overlap. I've reversed the order of your groups to make the logic simpler.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm not familiar with the way you're using two things, "enemy,colls", in the for loop. But, this gives me a TypeError(no matter the order of groups) saying  "'Enemy' object is not iterable". EDIT: Upon removing "enemy," from the for loop line, this seems to work somewhat. But, is not blitted to screen.

Comment: UPDATE: After playing around with it for a bit, the persisting problem is that the position received from enemy.rect.whatever is that of the last enemy to enter the screen, instead of the enemy in collision.